# Convert Javascript object to String in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angularJS and i'm having some issues with the below code. Basically what i'm trying to achieve is to search the spotify API for a term and retrieve the first playlist given to me, then grab the URI of the playlist and concatenate it to an embed url to be displayed in a page.

I can't seem to get the $scope.spotifySearch object to go into the $scope.playlisturi scope in a string format. any help would be appreciated.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, Spotify) {

  $scope.spotifySearch = Spotify.search('Top 40', 'playlist').then(function (data) {
    return (data.playlists.items[0].uri);
  });

  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }

  $scope.playlisturlfragment = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=";
  $scope.playlisturi = $scope.spotifySearch;
  $scope.playlisturl = {src:$scope.playlisturlfragment+$scope.playlisturi}

});
```

Comment: FYI: the library i'm using to search the spotify API is angular-spotify

Comment: This question implies you want JSON but I think what you want are URL query parameters.

Comment: in your `.then(..` function callback you can assign the uri to your `$scope.playlisturi`

Comment: I think [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) will help you.  That allows angular to modify a url.  Also possible is `ng-src`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu i'm already using ng-src, however all I get returned is [object Object]

Comment: @devqon I don't understand what you mean (bear in mind this is my first angular project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a **promise** to `spotifySearch` and I think what you want is the `uri` returned by the search.

There are basically two approaches to this problem.

1. Assign the value to `playlisturl` when the promise is resolved.
2. Assign the value to `playlisturl` when `spotifySearch` is changed.

Here's the first approach.

```
 $scope.playlisturlfragment = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=";
 Spotify.search('Top 40', 'playlist').then(function (data) {
     $scope.playlisturl = {src:$scope.playlisturlfragment+data.playlists.items[0].uri}
  });
```

The other way is to watch `spotifySearch` for changes.

```
 $scope.playlisturlfragment = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=";
 Spotify.search('Top 40', 'playlist').then(function (data) {
     $scope.spotifySearch = data.playlists.items[0].uri;
  });

 $scope.$watch('spotifySearch',function(value) {
     if(!value) return;
     $scope.playlisturl = {src:$scope.playlisturlfragment+value};
 });
```

Comment: why add the watch and not just update `$scope.playlisturl` in callback? Also might need `$apply`

Comment: First approach works perfectly, thanks for the help, I realise where I was going wrong now :)

Comment: I would opt for the first one

Comment: @charlietfl it's good to split logic from DOM related things. Perform the Spotify.search in the directive's controller, and update the DOM in the link.

Comment: I look your example. You use the $watch for wait the return of promise. For me this is ant-pattern. Use the $watch in development big projects can hurt the code if development changes the model in other part of code. The callback function guarantee unique comportament in app. In the situation you necessity two comportament. Whats you do? Create other variáble for $watch this?

Answer (score 1):

You assign a promise to your `$scope.spotifySearch`, not the real data (`$http` returns a promise). Instead you can do it like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, Spotify) {

    $scope.playlisturlfragment = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=";
    $scope.playlisturl = {
        src: ""
    }

    $scope.spotifySearch = Spotify.search('Top 40', 'playlist').then(function (data) {
        // use the callback to assign the uri to your object
        $scope.playlisturl.src = $scope.playlisturlfragment + data.playlists.items[0].uri;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular use promise for request. This promise is async, soon return value in then not work. For this use the callback function as:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, Spotify) {

    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    };

    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.search(function(uri){
            $scope.playlisturlfragment = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=";
            $scope.playlisturl = {src:$scope.playlisturlfragment + uri};
        });
    };

    $scope.search = function(callback){
        $scope.spotifySearch = Spotify.search('Top 40', 'playlist').then(function (data) {
            callback(data.playlists.items[0].uri);
        });
    };
});
```

Run the init method for look this example

Comment: converting promises into callbacks is an ant-pattern for me. It hides the benefits of promises.

Comment: I look your example. You use the $watch for wait the return of promise. For me this is ant-pattern. Use the $watch in development big projects can hurt the code if development changes the model in other part of code. The callback function guarantee unique comportament in app. In the situation you necessity two comportament. Whats you do? Create other variáble for $watch this?